# Setup Server Side Rendering Angular 4+ Application with Loopback/Strongloop

Tags: angular, angular5, loopback, server-side-rendering, angular-loopback

I have a Loopback-Server as backend for my angular application and it works great. To improve my SEO on my application I want to render the application on the server (ssr).

I have my angular application inside the client folder of the loopback server application

the /client/dist folder is where the generated angular files are stored.
the /client/frontend folder is where the source application is in.

[image]

my question is how to setup the `tsconfig.json` file.
my angularCompilerOptions look like this:

```
    "angularCompilerOptions": {
        "genDir": "../dist",
        "entryModule": "./src/app/app.module#AppModule"
    }
```

on top of that I generated a `app.server.module.ts` file inside the `src/app/` folder to export the `AppServerModule`.

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {ServerModule} from "@angular/platform-server";
import {AppModule} from "./app.module";
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ServerModule,
    AppModule
  ],
  bootstrap:[AppComponent]
})
export class AppServerModule { }
```

and a `server.ts` file inside the src/ folder:

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import { platformServer, renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server'
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core'
import { AppServerModuleNgFactory } from '../dist/ngfactory/src/app/app.server.module.ngfactory'
import * as express from 'express';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import { join } from 'path';

const PORT = 4000;

enableProdMode();

const app = express();

let template = readFileSync(join(__dirname, '..', 'dist', 'index.html')).toString();

app.engine('html', (_, options, callback) => {
  const opts = { document: template, url: options.req.url };

  renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, opts)
    .then(html => callback(null, html));
});

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', 'src')

app.get('*.*', express.static(join(__dirname, '..', 'dist')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { req });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`listening on http://localhost:${PORT}!`);
});
```

my question is:

- do I really need the express server inside the `server.ts` file ?
- can I tell loopback to serve the files already rendered ?
- how can I achieve SSR with Loopback ?

just for the completeness: I am using `angular 5.2.0` and `loopback 3.x`

thanks for all helpful answers

Comment: Is that problem solved @hart ?

Answer (score 1):

With Angular you must use [Universal](https://angular.io/guide/universal) if you want to make the app SEO friendly.

If you want another option then GoogleChrome recently launched [Rendertron](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/rendertron). It serve the rendered pages to Bots.